# LOAD DATA INFILE, LINES TERMINATES BY many spaces before CRLF

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile, loaddata

I have a large CSV file over which I have no control of its formatting where each line terminates with many white space characters before the CRLF.

The following statement works fine to import the CSV into MYSql, except the last field/column of each record imports with a trailing double quote.  It seems the `ENCLOSED BY '"'` statement is ignored when the line is terminated by many spaces before the carriage return/line feed.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\FILE.CSV' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS 
    TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Here you can see the hex of an excerpt showing the many spaces `20` before the line return `0D 0A` with the start of the next record.

> 75 6D 22 2C 22 59 22 2C 22 41 41 4D 22 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 0D 0A 22 20 41 41 4E 22 2C 22 41 65 72 6F 20 41 72 63 74 69 63 20 4C 74 64 22

This is:

```
"um\",\"Y\",\"AAM\"....r\n\" AAN\",\"Aero Arctic Ltd\""
```

Instead of having to trim the trailing `"` from the last imported column, I'd like to import the CSV without it!

Comment: It looks like someone's accidentally put in columnar data into a single field.

Comment: You can trim directly during the import, use `load data ... into table table_name (column_names,...,@var1) FIELD TERMINATED ...  set last_columnname = trim(@var1)`